# How to make CupertinoActivityIndicator fully white

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]
I want to change the barBackgroundColor  and primary Color fully white of CupertinoActivityIndicator but it show grey here is two colors one is white and the second one is grey i want to make both fully white.

```
 Container(
        height: 80,
        width: 80,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
        ),
        child: Theme(
            data: ThemeData(
                cupertinoOverrideTheme:
                    CupertinoThemeData(     brightness: Brightness.dark,
                      primaryColor: CupertinoColors.extraLightBackgroundGray,
                      barBackgroundColor: CupertinoColors.extraLightBackgroundGray,
                      scaffoldBackgroundColor: CupertinoColors.black,)),
            child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(animating: true, radius: 20,)),
      ),
```

i also change the color but it Still Not Wroking Please tell me how can i get fully white indicator

```
Container(
    height: 80,
    width: 80,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
    ),
    child: Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
            cupertinoOverrideTheme:
                CupertinoThemeData(
                  brightness: Brightness.dark,
                  primaryColor:   CupertinoDynamicColor.withBrightness(
                color: CupertinoColors.white,
                  darkColor: CupertinoColors.white,
                ),
                  barBackgroundColor:   CupertinoDynamicColor.withBrightness(
                    color: CupertinoColors.white,
                    darkColor: CupertinoColors.white,
                  ),
                  scaffoldBackgroundColor:   CupertinoDynamicColor.withBrightness(
                    color: CupertinoColors.white,
                    darkColor: CupertinoColors.white,
                  ),
                )),
        child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(animating: true, radius: 20,)),
  ),
```

Comment: Can you include an image that you are getting and the one you like to archive?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Please check it again i have added the picture

Comment: Are you trying to say all `bar` means indicator part will be fully white all time?

Comment: yes indicator part should be fully white

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CupertinoActivityIndicator no longer supports a custom color
[Click Here to check Answer](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42421)

Answer (score 2):

I found alot of folks onlile asking the same question, while the native platform allow modification it got me wondering why did the remove they parameter ?

Anyhow, a quick work around this would be using color filters like:

```dart
Widget withColor(Color color) => ColorFiltered(
      colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
        color,
        BlendMode.srcATop,
      ),
      child: const CupertinoActivityIndicator(),
    );
```